# How can i calculate or plot error of each class in CNN?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, classification, loss

I used this code for my project, but i want to calculate or plot error of each class.I have 6 class. how can i do?

```
def plot_history(net_history):
    history = network_history.history
    losses = history['loss']
    accuracies = history['acc']
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.plot(losses)

    plt.figure()
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.plot(accuracies)
```

## Create my model

```
myinput = layers.Input(shape=(100,200))
conv1 = layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(myinput)
conv2 = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(conv1)
flat = layers.Flatten()(conv2)
out_layer = layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')(flat)

mymodel = Model(myinput, out_layer)
mymodel.summary()
mymodel.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## train my model

```
network_history = mymodel.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128,epochs=5, validation_split=0.2)
plot_history(network_history)
```

## Evaluation

```
test_loss, test_acc = mymodel.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)

test_labels_p = mymodel.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to evaluate a classifier is the `classification_report` in scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

....

# Actual predictions here, not just probabilities
pred = numpy.round(mymodel.predict(X_test))
print(classification_report(Y_test, pred))
```

where `Y_test` is a list of one-hot vectors.

This will show you precision, recall and f1 measure for each class. The downside is that it only considers whether the prediction was correct or incorrect and doesn't incorporate the certainty of the model.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But when i used this code, I have this problem:precision recallf1-score support
0   0.00    0.00    0.00   23
1   0.00    0.00    0.00   23
2   0.00    0.00    0.00   23
3   0.00    0.00    0.00   23
4   0.00    0.00    0.00   23
5   0.00    0.00    0.00   23
micro avg       0.00    0.00    0.00   138
macro avg       0.00    0.00    0.00   138
weighted avg    0.00    0.00    0.00   138
samples avg     0.00    0.00    0.00   138

Comment: That could indicate a model that doesn't output a probability of more than 50% for any of the classes, in which case the simple way I used here will not predict any class membership at all. This could be an indication that your model is not flexible enough to do the classification or that you didn't train it long enough -- 5 epochs is not a lot, and the small size of the test set suggests that the training set might also be very small (which could also cause problems, depending on the complexity of the task). What is your input data?

Answer (score 0):

You have to train it like a binary classification problem and then you can use this code to make learning curves for different classes:

```
plt.plot(network_history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(network_history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```